# LG Escape 2 - bricked

Tags: rooting, adb, root-access, lg

I tried running a script that I [got online](http://smartphoneclinics.com/one-click-script-to-root-lg-escape-2-h443). I downloaded the whole file which included the `.bat` file. I tried running the `.bat` file while forgetting that I needed to download the drivers (from the same website). I canceled the script, got the drivers and tried running the script again - all the while messing around in developer mode (I hadn't known of the feature).

It ran successfully, but since it was running on my old family PC with Windows 7 running, it froze in the middle of installing the drivers, and I had to install them a second time. This time, the installation finished, but a notification popped up saying that the drivers were not successfully installed.

Since then, my phone will not move past the black start up screen, and I have to take the battery out in order to turn it off. I would like to return the device in any condition, whether it be data free or not. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have updated the post. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your phone is bricked.

Try downloading the StockRom or some CustomRom that is compatible to your phone and flash it. This might help you.

If you are wandering about all these terms Bricked, StockRom, CustomRom and flash. [Here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-meant-by-firmware-stock-custom-roms-and-flashing-guide/) is a good article that might help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can go to [xdadevelopers.com](http://www.xda-developers.com) (it's the most popular forum for Android developer news and downloads) and go to your phone subforum. Grab the firmware of your model number and version of the phone. Go into download mode in your phone (don't know how to get there on the LG), flash the zip. Not sure of the last step because in a Samsung you just have to use Odin to flash the firmware, so I'm not sure of the program used in an LG phone.

You'll probably lose root though. Also, this is assuming you're soft bricked (meaning you can go to fastboot/recovery mode. If you can't and you've tried all possible ways, you're hard bricked and need to go to your carrier store to fix it).

Answer (score 0):

[Link to firmware](https://www.easy-firmware.com/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=17236) - the download is a bit complicated, though.

Comment: Translated with Google in light of the [Non-English policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/). Do note that the majority of the people who read this QA strip expects English. If you have any qualms about my translation, feel free to further correct it.